# Rails 4 generic parent model with more specific child models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, activerecord, extend, polymorphic-associations

I am working on my first real Rails 4 app and I have run into a problem with my design.

Currently I have a "Service" model which started out with attributes such as name, online_status, ip, dns_name, port, and service_type. This model has evolved to include many methods and attributes for specific service_types (like auth_tokens, etc.) and thus it is very overgrown. The columns added to the database to accommodate the needs of the different types of services make this model act like a ghetto version of STI without separate classes/models.

The Service model also has methods such as ping() which is used to determine the online_status. I believe the types of services are different enough to warrant their own separate tables because each service seems to have many unique properties and methods.

Example:

A generic service has: name, ip, dns_name, online_status, etc...

A specific service such as Plex will have: name, ip, dns_name, online_status, username, password, auth_token, etc...

The issue, is that I would like to be able to access the more specific types of services from their parent Service class. So when I create a view, I can loop through all the generic services and the more specific services as if they were all the same type of service (or at least be able to access all services in some simple way without looping through each type and appending them).

I also need to access the specific types of models on their own, so doing something like @couchpotatos.each in my view will only go through the instances of the Couchpotato class.

Controllers play into this confusion too since I don't exactly know how to have a single page display all these different types of models from the same controller.

Criticism is welcome! I'm learning, so if this desired design absolutely bonkers, please let me know :D

Comment: I am little confused by the association you are attempting to create.  Are you wanting to like multi specific services to a single generic service.  For example, do you want to create a record for the Plex connection, then link it to multiple Plex accounts/clients?  Or are you just trying to create mulitple service models/tables for each service type?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am attempting to clarify the structure of the classes/models/db tables. My goal is to not have to repeat myself for things like name, ip, dns_name, online_status etc. so I am attempting to find a way to allow instantiation of the parent class with just these basic attributes and also be able extend upon/add to those with more specific attributes and methods like auth_token and get_auth_token() respectively. Does that help explain my goals?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's give it shot. I hope I understand your current situation, but the first thing a thought of is using a `ServiceConcern` containing the shared logic of a service. So a basic example would be:

```
module Service
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :user
  end

  def ping
    "pong"
  end
end

class PlexService < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Service

  def ping
    "plex-pong"
  end
end
```

You would create a new model for each Service implementation that MUST have the stuff a Service should have (in the case above it would be a `user_id`)

The problem remaining would be a generic way to find all the implementations of the Service concern.

To achieve that, you have to implement a STI, where the Base object would be "Service" with user_id and a type (in the case described above) and implementations with their overrides

Comment: I hadn't heard of concerns before, this seems like an interesting way to navigate around the issue of shared code. I'm guessing I can put validations in there too based on what I have found after a little research. When I get some refactoring time I'll try this out and see if it will work for what I'm trying to accomplish, thanks!